# How to create a physical UX Innovation board?

Tags: dashboard, team

I would like to have a physical board where all the innovations that the UX team worked on would be exposed to the other teams (dev, marketing etc.). It would give a better exposition and understanding on our work, a new source of feedback and would also help the UX team to keep track of the ideas/concept that have been considered.

The thing is many innovations are not implemented in our product because of time, cost, or because it doesn't seem important at the moment. Some are just ideas that no one really requested but could benefit the company. But it is not impossible that they get a second chance to be developed in the future.

Once I worked in a video game company and the art team used to expose their art concept on a board visible to everyone. I would like to implement something similar but for UI / UX.

Any resource, article, book, advice, tutorial, personal experience, ideas that could help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If it is just one office building, then it can be a physical push-pin board. But if you would like people from multiple offices to have a look, you will need to have it online on something like [Trello](https://trello.com/). We have gone a bit further in our organisation and created a separate site to collect such ideas, particularly for the research stories; there is a blog for other purposes. A site like this however cannot capture every little idea. For that tools like Trello work the best because the board can have organisation-wide visibility. However, these are subjective.